# Ajax call to GET action in controller is not invoking

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call an MVC controller action using JQuery Ajax GET method and also passing the two parameters.
Problem is the action is not getting triggered instead it gives 404 error. Below goes my code please point out what I am missing.

Action in controller

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetViewGridData(List<Models.ItemModel> gridData, int Category_Id = 0, int SubCategory_Id = 0)
{    
    //code goes here
}
```

Ajax call

```
var Category_Id = $("#CategoryView").val();
var SubCategory_Id = $("#SubCategoryView").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/Item/GetViewGridData/",
    data: {Category_Id:Category_Id,SubCategory_Id:SubCategory_Id},
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
        //});
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Comment: 404 means the url you are trying is not valid. It might be a good idea to make use the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the correct url.(Ex :`url: "@Url.Action("GetViewGridData","Item"`,). There could be other reasons as well (wrong routing definition etc!). can you try to access the url in a browser ?

Comment: Not related, but remove the `List<Models.ItemModel> gridData` parameter from you method (your not sending any data related to that)

Comment: What @StephenMuecke said. You aren't sending any `gridData` to the controller method, since it isn't an optional parameter it assumes that this method will only be invoked if the data is preset (or atleast null values)

Comment: I am using gridData to pass it to partial view for rendering the webgrid from there. I resolved the issue when I found the above action was replaced using jquery on runtime so after removing jquery replace method it starts firing GetViewGridData action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function GetViewGridData() {
var Category_Id = $("#CategoryView").val();
var SubCategory_Id = $("#SubCategoryView").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/GetViewGridData/Item?SubCategory_Id='+ SubCategory_Id +'& Category_Id='+ Category_Id,
        method: "GET",
        cache: false
    }).done(function (result) {
        //You will get the data in result
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for attribute routing - enable it in your route config
`routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()`

and in your `Item` controller

```
[RoutePrefix("item")]
public class ItemController: Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("GetViewGridData")]
  public JsonResult GetViewGridData(List<Models.ItemModel> gridData, int   Category_Id = 0, int SubCategory_Id = 0)
  {    
    //code goes here
  }
}
```

*As @Stephen commented, remove unwanted params from the action as well if you are not using it*